# Create dynamic library with cmake

Tags: cmake

**libxxx.c**:

```
void func(void)
{
    aaa(); //this function not defined!
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
aux_source_directory(. DIR_LIB_SRC)
include_directories(.)
add_library(xxx SHARED ${DIR_LIB_SRC})
```

Running

```
cmake && make
```

succeed.

Why no errors are generated here?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CMake specific. Your code is relying two C compiler related behaviors.

Calling a function without a prototype is possible, but considered and error. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Call_to_a_function_without_a_prototype

Library may have dependencies. Your library depends on liker to find a function `aaa()`. Also linker does not know about prototypes, so this is not error anymore.

If you try to link this library, you will see the linking error.

Comment: But why when I change libxxx.c to libxxx.cpp, I can see the error that the aaa function is not declared during the compilation process?

Comment: i have set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc)